# Access to wrapped Polly policy

Tags: c#, polly, circuit-breaker, retry-logic, bulkhead

If I wrap some polices is it possible to acces them from the wrapped policy?

example:

```
var handle = Policy.Handle<Exception>();//.OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.IsSuccessStatusCode == false);

var timeout = Policy.TimeoutAsync(() => TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)  /*loginConnectorOptions.Timeout*/);
var retry = handle.RetryAsync(retryCount: 3);
var cb = handle.CircuitBreakerAsync(exceptionsAllowedBeforeBreaking: 3, durationOfBreak: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
var bulkhead = Policy.BulkheadAsync(maxParallelization: 4, maxQueuingActions: 20);
_lcPolicy = Policy.WrapAsync(bulkhead, retry, cb, timeout);
_lcPolicy.WithPolicyKey("LoginConnector");
```

I would like to access the circuit breaker to get access to the state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>There is not currently a way within Polly to interrogate a configured `PolicyWrap` to obtain the policies it consists of.  This could be added: please raise a feature request as an Issue on [Polly's Github](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly), if desired.</s>

From the code example presented in the question, of course you have the circuit-breaker in the variable `cb`.  So for now you could pass the value of `cb` to where you need it, and access `cb.CircuitState`.

**EDIT**: [Polly v5.6.0](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#560) now provides the ability to obtain the policies within a `PolicyWrap` natively, using the [`.GetPolices<>` (and related) methods](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap#methods).

Comment: Issue (with further discussion) now exists on Polly github: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/312

Comment: Edited to highlight new Polly feature providing what the OP asked for.